# Принтеры HP постоянно меняют свои серийники

Tags: linux, hp

Установил через hp-setup. Установился как

```
Device URI: hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Professional_M1132_MFP?serial=000000000QH44H85PR1a
```

Через некоторое время перестает печатать. Удаляю и устанавливаю драйвер - встает как

```
Device URI: hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Professional_M1132_MFP?serial=000000000QH44H85SI1c
```

Через день, неделю или 3 месяца он снова поменяет серийник. Как установить hplip принтер так чтоб он оставался на месте?

SI1c принтер включился в режиме установки драйверов.

PR1a - в режиме принтера.

но суфикс не исправляется когда подгружается hp-plugin

Comment: слишком мало информации. Вот у меня hp и нечего не меняет годами. Может на машине левые программы есть? или под раздачу просто попало от HP

Comment: LaserJet M1132 MFP, P1102 выпадают

Comment: https://jacobsalmela.com/2015/02/05/change-the-serial-number-on-hp-printers-using-printer-job-language-and-netcat-ftp/ - кто то меняет или просто "ну так случилось, что в документе попали правильные символы"

Comment: интересно, попробую послать это в усб

Comment: @KoVadim их принудительно никто не меняет... оно само)

Comment: А смысл? Хотя вон HPE отозвала аккаунты. Но тут мне сложно судить

Comment: они меня уже лет 5 бесят этим поведением. то долго стоят нормально, по 2 раза в день переключаются

Comment: Может они просто сломаны изначально были?